# How to clear input text box, after obtaining the result from API in React

Tags: reactjs, api

I need help with my React weather app. I am searching for a city to obtain a weather forecast from API. Everything is working. When I enter the city name and search, result is appearing. But I want to clear the input text when the result is obtained. I did the following resetForm, It is clearing the input field but at the same time clearing the result from API.

```
class Form extends React.Component{

    render(){
        resetForm = () => {
        this.refs.inputId.value="";
      }
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.props.getWeather}>
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Type a city name..." ref="inputID" />
                <button>Search</button>
            </form>
        );
    }


};

getWeather = async (e) =>{
    this.setState({loading: true});
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const api_call = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
    const data = await api_call.json();

    if(city){
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({
        temperature: data.main.temp,
        city: data.name,
        humidity: data.main.humidity,
        description: data.weather[0].description,
        error: "",
        loading:false,

      });
    }else{
      this.setState({ 
        temperature: undefined,
        city: undefined,
        humidity: undefined,
        description: undefined,
        error: "Please enter the city and the country name!",
        loading:false,

      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Controlled Components`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) is the simplest way to do this.

In parent component, you need to maintain a `state` variable and change handler function and pass it to the `Form` component,

```
state = {
    inputCity: ''   //You can add this in your existing state
}
```

And the change handler function,

```
onCityChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputCity : e.target.value})
}
```

Now you caan pass them to your `Form` component,

```
<Form inputCity={this.state.inputCity} onCityChange={this.onCityChange} getWeather={this.getWeather}/>
```

You `Form` component should be,

```
class Form extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.props.getWeather}>
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Type a city name..." value={this.props.inputCity} onChange={this.props.onCityChange}/>
                <button>Search</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
};
```

Your `getWeather` function should be,

```
getWeather = async (e) =>{
    this.setState({loading: true});
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = this.state.inputCity;   //take the city from state directly
    const api_call = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
    const data = await api_call.json();

    if(data){   //instead of city it should be data here
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({
        temperature: data.main.temp,
        city: data.name,
        humidity: data.main.humidity,
        description: data.weather[0].description,
        error: "",
        loading:false,
        inputCity: ""   //here you can clear the city 
      });
    }else{
      this.setState({ 
        temperature: undefined,
        city: undefined,
        humidity: undefined,
        description: undefined,
        error: "Please enter the city and the country name!",
        loading:false,

      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I have modified your code a little to use state, ref is fine but is usually considered not the most efficient approach:

**`this.setState` has a callback as well since it's an async operation, you can make your API request after loading is set to true, after the response is successful or fails (as soon as the response from the server is recieved), set the loading state to false and clear the input.**

The rest of your code is fine, except for a few tweaks, it will now work.
Read more about controlled inputs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class Form extends React.Component{
  state = {
    loading:false,
    temperature: '',
    city: '',
    humidity: '',
    description: '',
    error: '',
    cityName: ''
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ city: e.target.value });
  }

  getWeather =  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({loading: true}, async () => {
      const {city} = this.state;
      const api_call = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
      const data = await api_call.json();

      if(data){
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          temperature: data.main.temp,
          cityName: data.name,
          humidity: data.main.humidity,
          description: data.weather[0].description,
          error: "",
          loading:false,

        }, () => {
          this.setState({ city: '' })
        });
      }else{
        this.setState({ 
          temperature: undefined,
          cityName: undefined,
          humidity: undefined,
          description: undefined,
          error: "Please enter the city and the country name!",
          loading:false,

        }, () => {
          this.setState({ city: '' })
        });
      }
    });
}
  render(){
      return(
          <form onSubmit={this.getWeather}>
              <input type="text" 
                name="city" 
                value={this.state.city}
                placeholder="Type a city name..." 
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
              <button>Search</button>
          </form>
      );
  }


};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, rootElement);
```

**Sandbox link**: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-browser-e2rh8?fontsize=14